# Object element behvior inside epub3 file

Tags: svg, xhtml, epub

I am currently upgrading from EPUB2 to EPUB3,I did some major changes to the xhtml file like changing the figures container element from

`<img alt="509643.fig.004" src="images/509643.fig.004.svg"/>`

to

```
<object name="509643.fig.001" data="images/509643.fig.001.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
```

(P.S i use SVG format),when i tested the output,i found that half or more of the figures have been disappeared inside EPUB file(blank space but selectable),although they are fine inside the xhtml file,My question is,Is there an issue when using the object element inside EPUB file?

Comment: What reader are you testing the ePub files on?

Comment: ADE over Windows7 OS .